# Can my open-source package adhere to GPL/LGPL v3 if it has a closed-source dependency?

Tags: licensing, gpl, lgpl

My plugin dll depends on the presence of Microsoft Excel on a client computer. Excel is not part of the OS. The dependency is a 2 way transfer of data, the dll I created only works if run from inside Excel.

The code of my application is all open source. Other than the dependency on Excel, there is a dependency on another package. There are 2 (3) Scenarios I'm wondering about:

- Scenario 1: If the non-Excel dependency is GPL, then my plugin must be GPL also, meaning I have to distribute source code of all my dependencies (except kernel/operating system stuff) - which I don't have for Excel. Does this mean I cannot reference the GPL package as my project cannot adhere to the license terms?
- Scenario 2: I remove the second dependency and only depend on Excel. I want to make my plugin LGPL so other people can build it into their code. Again, can I *choose* to make my code LGPL if it depends on something closed source; how could someone who derives a new plugin from my one (inheriting the LGPL license) disclose the full source of their transitive dependency to Excel?

  - Scenario 2b: I depend on Excel + derived code from an LGPL library, forcing me to inherit LGPL or GPL. I choose LGPL but can I adhere to that without Excel source code? Is this back to Scenario 1?

My end goal; license the plugin with a weak copyleft license like LGPLv3 or Mozilla License 2.0. Ideally allow me to derive code from another weak copyleft starting point (I have been gifted some code under GPL I may be able to negotiate it to LGPL)

Comment: Did you check the GPL FAQ?, Especially the entry ["Can I apply the GPL when writing a plug-in for a nonfree program?"](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLPluginsInNF)

Comment: Does this answer your question ["Can I link (and distribute) a closed source library within my (GPL) open source software?"](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/can-i-link-and-distribute-a-closed-source-library-within-my-gpl-open-source)